# How can we improve bluetooth pairing experience?

Tags: usability

If you have several devices to pair with, it becomes a painful exercise unpairing and repairing with different devices. For an example, my car's system remembers multiple bluetootb devices, but unpairing and repairing with another  device is a hassle. Can this experience be improved in some way?

EDIT: We can consider a hypothetical situation where there are no technical constraints, only the requirement to pair safely with one's own devices (security issue).

Answer (score 1):

This solution might not work for all cases, but if it was possible to physically TOUCH the 2 devices you want to pair for a brief moment.

This would be quite an intuitive way of pairing devices provided we can come up with a technology for this.

Answer (score 1):

@Ameen, that would require NFC and not all devices have that.

Answer: pairing devices require security and thus increasing the number of steps. For Android devices it is possible by skipping the step of asking password and just asking permission in yes or no.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an Android and IOS app for bluetooth device.
After installing that app on a phone a user can link bluetooth with multiple device with the help of one device (that is his phone)